# Permission denied: Writing to CSV from Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Im receiving the below error when attempting to write to a CSV file. I checked my file and folder settings and global availability is set. How do I fix this? Code is below as well.

I have tried with both open and closed files.

```
File "c:\Users\toril\OneDrive\Documents\Pokemon AI\base 1 test.py", line 19, in <module>
    with open ('pokemontest1.csv', 'w', newline='') as csv_file:
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'pokemontest1.csv'


    from importlib.resources import Resource
from string import capwords
from unicodedata import name
from pokemontcgsdk import RestClient
from pokemontcgsdk import Card
from pokemontcgsdk import Set
from pokemontcgsdk import Type
from pokemontcgsdk import Supertype
from pokemontcgsdk import Subtype
from pokemontcgsdk import Rarity
from pokemontcgsdk import querybuilder
from pokemontcgsdk import RestClient
import csv

RestClient.configure('xxxxxxxxxxxx')

fields = ['Data']

with open ('pokemontest1.csv', 'w', newline='') as csv_file:
    Cards = Card.where(q='set.name:generations supertype:pokemon')
for card in Cards:
    rows = [card.name, card.types, card.supertype, card.subtypes, card.number, card.rarity, card.nationalPokedexNumbers, card.id, card.set.name, card.set.series]
    
    csvwriter = csv.writer(csv_file)
    csvwriter.writerow(fields)
    csvwriter.writerows(rows)
```

Comment: It’s opened on my vs code. Does that matter?

Comment: I will have to move the location of the file most likely because I have this folder opened in vs code. Let me try!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason it wasnt working is because as soon as you exit the `with` statement the file is closed and no longer writeable.

For example:

```
with open(filename) as file:
    contents = file.read()

contents = file.read()  # <-- will throw error
```

What your code was doing was equivalent to this:

```
csv_file = open("pokemontest2.csv", "w", newline='')
Cards = Card.where(q='set.name:generations supertype:pokemon')
csv_file.close()

for card in Cards:
    rows = [card.name, card.types, card.supertype, card.subtypes, card.number, card.rarity, card.nationalPokedexNumbers, card.id, card.set.name, card.set.series]
    csvwriter = csv.writer(csv_file)  # csv_file is no longer open
    csvwriter.writerow(fields)
    csvwriter.writerows(rows)
```

By moving the `with` statement down, now all of the logic that deals with the csv_file is inside the `with` block.

```
Cards = Card.where(q='set.name:generations supertype:pokemon')
for card in Cards:
    rows = [card.name, card.types, card.supertype, card.subtypes, card.number, card.rarity, card.nationalPokedexNumbers, card.id, card.set.name, card.set.series]
    
with open ('pokemontest1.csv', 'w', newline='') as csv_file:
    csvwriter = csv.writer(csv_file)  # the file is still open
    csvwriter.writerow(fields)
    csvwriter.writerows(rows)
```

Comment: Do you by chance know why it is just printing 1 character per cell when it does go to my CSV? Really appreciate this feedback.

Comment: @ToriElstrom    It shouldn't be printing anything from what I can tell... there are no print statements in your code.  I am not familiar with the library you are using though.

Answer (score -2):

Three things fixed it:

1. Moving the file outside of VS code.
2. Closing the file, changing the name and allowing it to rewrite a new one.
3. Moving the With Open statement down in my code.